# window.close() in XPages

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus, serverside-javascript

I am having a Xpage with some links. One of my link call **EXIT** having `window.close()` to close the current tab in browser.

In browser when I am opening the document(Xpage holds the document) from the view and clicking on the **EXIT** link, it closes the current tab/window.

Whereas, I am redirecting the same xpage from SSJS using `context.redirectToPage()` . When I clicking on the **EXIT** link, it is not closing the tab/window.

In Javascript console: **Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script**

Anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance,
Karthick

Comment: See my answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682492/how-do-i-close-my-window-in-xpage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the Javascript console says: Window.close() needs a window.open() to work.

See http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Whats_New_in_852_for_XPages#window.close%28%29+support

**Update:**
You can create your response document using client-side JS - including opening the window. The following will do that:

```
// get parent document id    
docid='#{javascript:document.getNoteID()}';

// create the URL
url="response.xsp?action=newDocument&parentId="+docid;

// open a new window with the response document
window.open(url);
```

Comment: I am creating a response document for the current document when clicking on the link. The only way is that I have redirected the page.  So any other solution to make is work...?

Comment: Thanks... I will try this out... Whereas I am pushing more than 65 field values from parent document to response document before opening, so that I went for SSJS... I will try pushing those values in afterPageLoad of the response document... Any other simpler way to do this...?

Comment: You could look at creating the response document in a dialog in order to avoid opening a new window. Good luck with your solution.

Answer (score 3):

"In Javascript console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script"

Thats you're answer to the question. Javascript can't close tabs / windows which are not created by javascript.

You could try the following:

[How to close browser window](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/350.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this trick im using.

```
window.open('', '_self', '');

window.close();
```