# How to close xpages in notes client? I use CSJS window.close but it's not working

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpinc

I'm doing an xpinc application.

I followed the example in [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Whats_New_in_852_for_XPages#window.close%28%29+support) and modified it. Currently the close button is on my main page.

The customer wanted a close button instead of the normal 'X' to close. But the example suggests that I should create 2 xpages.

On page1 I should create a button with `window.open(xpage2.xsp)` and only then `window.close()` in a button in xpage2 will work. How do I `window.close()` when I have no `window.open()` to begin with?

I've check Demo Discussion xpage and OneUI but there's nothing like that. I tried putting `window.open(xpage1.xsp)` on xpage1 onClientLoad event but that's not working too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the page is opened by window.open, then window.close works fine. otherwise it does not work. Please see the following question, same question has already appeared in stackoverflow.

[How to close the xpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682492/how-do-i-close-my-window-in-xpage)

For my project, I redirected the page into my home page.

And I am also searching the fine solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today and found this very interesting article by Fredrik Norling, which helped:
http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2013/ibm-notes-domino-9-01-xpages-fixlist

There is a new notes.ini (client) parameter:

```html
XPagesXulAllowScriptsToCloseWindows=1
```

together with the SSJS code

```html
view.postScript("window.close()");
```

worked for me - the tab / window in the Notes Client could be closed from the XPage.

Strange thing that we have to add this parameter, maybe it has something to do with security...